# Installing an rpm on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-recommendation, ups

So, i've discovered how to intsall an rpm on ubuntu, but the choices for download that i have are for Fedora, or OpenSUSE11.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Desktop running a Gnome3 shell if that matters.

I have a new UPS which only seems to allow for [windows or those two](https://tripplite.com/products/power-alert-local) is the site i'm downloading from, and not that you need it, but the model number is BCPRO600 just in case anyone is bored enough to wander around the site like i did and see something i may have missed, or if you know of any generic software that would cover the basics and work just as well; this is my first UPS.

Now, it's for a home system, so it's not 100% important i have the monitoring software installed as this is for a home system and 99% of the time i'm there and can shut things down myself; but it would be nice to cover that other 1% cuz murphy's law.

Comment: Have you tried the native software? "nut" https://networkupstools.org/ howto: https://blog.shadypixel.com/monitoring-a-ups-with-nut-on-debian-or-ubuntu-linux/  OR http://www.apcupsd.org/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/apcupsd

Comment: @Rinzwind i have not, but i shall give them a go to see if they solve my problem; i'll let you know in case it needs to be a real answer for you.